# httplib error on socket.gaierror:

Tags: python, httplib

I want to get the Url status for websites with the below code. For one website (webscraper.io), I got an error. My script is:

```
import httplib
url = "http://webscraper.io/"
if 'http' in url:
     url = url.replace('http://', '').strip()
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(url)
conn.request("GET",'')
r1 = conn.getresponse()
print 'r1.Status code=', r1.status
```

I got the below errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "TestSatusline.py", line 23, in <module>
     conn.request("GET",'')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1017, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1051, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1013, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 864, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 826, in send
     self.connect()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 807, in connect
     self.timeout, self.source_address)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
     for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
 socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Does anybody has any idea?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

after

```
if 'http' in url:
     url = url.replace('http://', '').strip()
```

in your code , url is `webscraper.io/`, it should be `webscraper.io`

use `urlparse`

```
import httplib
import urlparse

url = "http://webscraper.io/"
o = urlparse.urlparse(url)
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(o.netloc)
conn.request("GET",'')
r1 = conn.getresponse()
print 'r1.Status code=', r1.status
```

output

```
r1.Status code= 200
```

you could take a look at requests. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/